# scroll view on xcode using swift with 3 image laayers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, scrollview

I have three image layers , two will go from left to right while the 3rd layer will go from right to left by the same amount.

I know how to go from left to right but opposite direction isn't working.
what to do??

I tried this:

```
float w = scrollView.frame.size.width;
float h = scrollView.frame.size.height;
float newPosition = scrollView.contentOffset.x+w; 
CGRect toVisible = CGRectMake(newPosition, 0, w, h);
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:toVisible animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

your question has a swift tag while it is written in objective-c ?
use the right tags so people can help you.
~ i mainly use swift though.

Comment: i would like to know if any solution in obj-c or swift is present to this issue